# CSS Image Sprite Positioning on iPad

Tags: css, ipad

this is my first post.

I'm using CSS image sprites on a website I am building.  I've run both the HTML and the CSS through a validator which suggests the code is all correct, but I'm running into a discrepancy between how the image sprites appear on an iPad vs a computer.

On the iPad, the 5th sprite (contact) appears below the image sprites rather than at the bottom of the main image like all the others.  I'm just not sure how to fix it.

The website is http://www.pureelegancehair.com.au/index-real.htm and the stylesheet is located at http://www.pureelgancehair.com.au/main-style.css .

The HTML is as follows:

```
<IMG SRC="images/top.png" ID="MainIMG" ALT="Main Menu Image">

<ul class="cssmenu">
    <li class="salon"><a href="salon.htm" title="Salon"></a></li>
    <li class="services"><a href="services.htm" title="Services"></a></li>
    <li class="products"><a href="#" title="Products"></a></li>
    <li class="gallery"><a href="gallery.htm" title="Gallery"></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#" title="Contact Us"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
ul.cssmenu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; left: 182px; top: 437px;
    }
ul.displace {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5000px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li {
    float: left;
    }
ul.cssmenu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 192px;
    height: 99px;
    background: url('images/sprite.png');
    }   


ul.cssmenu li.salon a {
    background-position: 0 0;    }

ul.cssmenu li.services a {
    background-position: -192px 0;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.products a {
    background-position: -384px 0;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.gallery a {
    background-position: -576px 0;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.contact a {
    background-position: -768px 0;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.salon a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -99px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.services a:hover {
    background-position: -192px -99px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.products a:hover {
    background-position: -384px -99px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.gallery a:hover {
    background-position: -576px -99px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.contact a:hover {
    background-position: -768px -99px;
    }
```

I'm just not sure what I am doing wrong, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: The iPad has a resolution of 1024 (wide).  your content is wider than that, so the last `<li>` is falling onto the next line. It's not just iPad, it's any device (including desktops) that have smaller screens.  Try resizing your browser to 1024 and you'll see

Comment: Is there a reason you are using images for these links rather than just text?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the background-size the natural size of the sprite:

```
ul.cssmenu li.salon a {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-size: **width-value lenght-value**;
}
```